# Webhost with own handler?

Tags: python, handler

Is there a webhost that let's me use my own handler? I have developed a Python 3 handler, however I haven't found any webhost where I can use my own handler...

Does anyone know one?

Comment: Usually the typical shared hosting companies are not very good for anything but the average PHP/MySQL stuff.

Comment: exactly :(, I have written my own handler but I'm afraid to launch it on my home network, so I'm looking for a webhost, the only option atm is hiring a vpn :(

Comment: A VPS (VPN is something completely different) is probably the best choice anyway if you don't want to spend money on a dedicated machine. Another option could be something like Heroku... Never used them though, so don't know how good they are.